# Uncaught AssertionError: path must be a string error in Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, node-webkit

I'm getting the following error in my simple example using node-webkit:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: path must be a string
```

index.html

```
//base.js

require(["test"], function(test) {
    test.init();
});

//test.js

define(function(){
   window.c = window.console;
   return {
       init: function(){
           c.log('test.init');
       },

       destroy: function(){
           c.log('test.destroy');
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for providing these two options.  Both seem to be great ways of getting your app to work in node-wekbit and the regular browser.

I'll likely be using the "requirejs" option since it's a less hack-y.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the new version of RequireJS has a function called: `requirejs()` in addition to `require()` to avoid conflicts with node's `require()`.

Answer (score 4):

node provides its own require() so I had to make a copy of it `window.requireNode` and then add it back in the `base.js` callback:

```
<script>
    window.requireNode = window.require;
    window.require = undefined;
</script>

<script data-main="js/base" src="/bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>


require(["test"], function(test) {
    window.require = window.requireNode;
    test.init();
});
```